# Service Fabric SDK 2.4.145 and Runtime 5.4.145 links or Standalone Installer

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Does anyone have links to the specific version of Service Fabric SDK 2.4.145 and Runtime 5.4.145?

They would probably be in similar format to the links below:

Runtime: http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/9/6/C9680A4C-291F-4A6F-B699-26FF704577BA/MicrosoftServiceFabric.5.1.163.9590.msi

SDK: http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/9/6/C9680A4C-291F-4A6F-B699-26FF704577BA/MicrosoftServiceFabricSDK.2.1.163.msi

(alternatively some place I could get them from would also work)

Comment: Usually, every [release post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureservicefabric/) has a link on runtime and SDK if you will open attached document.

Comment: Thx, will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a best practice it's best to update to the latest version of the tools if possible. Here are the links for 2.4.145:

Runtime: http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/B/4/9B437FCC-E78F-4DAA-A2D8-CC5A5BF9E76F/MicrosoftServiceFabric.5.4.145.9494.msi

SDK: http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/B/4/9B437FCC-E78F-4DAA-A2D8-CC5A5BF9E76F/MicrosoftServiceFabricSDK.2.4.145.msi

VS Tools (en-us): http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/B/4/9B437FCC-E78F-4DAA-A2D8-CC5A5BF9E76F/MicrosoftAzureServiceFabricTools.VS140.en-us.msi

Standalone Installer: http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/3/6/836E3E99-A300-4714-8278-96BC3E8B5528/5.4.145.9494/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceFabric.WindowsServer.5.4.145.9494.zip

Edit: Please keep in mind the support dates of SF versions at the link below. 5.4.* goes out of support May 10, 2017. After this date some links may not be reachable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-support#supported-service-fabric-versions